# How to export denormalized AppEngine Datastore objects to BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-bigquery

I have created a pipeline to extract an AppEngine datastore object to Cloud Storage and finally to BigQuery following those [instructions](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery#code). This works well.

My goal now is to denormalize several objects that have relationships in my AppEngine datastore, and store this result in a large BigQuery table. But I do not see any InputReader in the [AppEngine MapReduce library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/readers_writers#RecordsReader) that can directly read from a datastore query.

So my question: what do you suggest is the best way to 1. join all the datastore tables 2. load the result (millions of rows) using MapReduce into GCS, then BigQuery?

Do I need to create a new datastore table in which I would copy the denormalized data, and use DatastoreInputReader to load this table to GCS, then BigQuery? I am looking for a way to save this unnecessary step.

Comment: Did you consider using JOINs across tables instead? https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#joins

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the joins would have to be done manually in BigQuery. It means I'd have to 1) load each datastore object individually to BigQuery, then 2) do the joins in BigQuery and store the results in a final BQ table. That's 2 steps to coordinate manually. I'd like the whole process to be automatic.

Comment: No, you do not have to do step 2. You can simply use JOINs in your BQ queries. As for step 1. - you need to load data into BQ anyhow.

Comment: It seems you're right! I was under the impression that the number of joins in a query were limited in BigQuery. Or maybe that was in the past. I'll give it a try.